# Android Studio - "waiting for target device to come online"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run an application developed in Android Gingerbread (API 10) emulator in Android Studio 2.3.2.

When running, it shows the message,"waiting for target device to come online" and it stays on that even after the emulator has come online, and does not go beyond that point.
I tried to:
 1. Update libraries
 2. Restart the PC
 3. Stop the emulator from AVD

However the application runs successfully on my mobile with Android Naught 7.1.1, but I want to test the app in Gingerbread environment which on the emulator I am not able to do.

I am not able to understand where exactly do I need to check for such error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too when using Gingerbread armeabi and armeabi-v7a images. Nothing helped. I fixed it by using x86 image.

If you don't see device in `$ adb devices`, try to run:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```